# Next.js 13 how to fetch cookie on client side and server side

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a function **myFetch** which is a wrapper for **fetch** to add token in the header

```
import clientCookies from "js-cookie";
import {cookies} from "next/headers";

const myFetch = async (...args) => {
let token
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  // client side
  token = clientCookies.get("authToken")
} else {
  // server side
  serverCookies = cookies()
  token = serverCookies.get("authToken").value
}

args[1].headers = {"Authorization": `bearer ${token}`}
const res = await fetch(...args)
const data = await res.json()
return data
}
```

But I am receiving error when calling this function client side

```
You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials
```

Is there any way I can "import {cookies} from 'next/headers'" server side only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally import each module based on the current type of the window object. If it is undefined; Import the server module, if not the client module:

```js
const myFetch = async (...args) => {
  let token;
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    const { cookies: serverCookies } = await import("next/headers");
    token = serverCookies().get("authToken").value;
  } else {
    const { default: clientCookies } = await import("js-cookie");
    token = clientCookies.get("authToken");
  }

  args[1].headers = { Authorization: `bearer ${token}` };
  const res = await fetch(...args);
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
- (axios/client-axios.ts): Axios configuration for the client-side. 
- (axios/server-axios.ts): Axios configuration for the server-side.
- (axios/index.ts) :This file dynamically imports the appropriate Axios 
   configuration based on the environment.
// axios/client-axios.ts
import axios, {
  AxiosInstance
}
from "axios";
import {
  API_BASE_URL
} from "../../lib/constant";
import {
  getCookie
} from "cookies-next";

const clientAxiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${getCookie("accessToken")}`,
  },
});

export default clientAxiosInstance;

// axios/server-axios.ts
import axios, {
  AxiosInstance
} from "axios";
import {
  API_BASE_URL
} from "../../lib/constant";
import {
  cookies
} from "next/headers";

const serverAxiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies().get("accessToken")?.value}`,
  },
});

export default serverAxiosInstance;

// axios/index.ts
import {
  AxiosInstance
} from "axios";
let axiosInstance: AxiosInstance;

if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  axiosInstance = require("@/config/axios/server-axios").default;
} else {
  axiosInstance = require("@/config/axios/client-axios").default;
}

export default axiosInstance;

// example-usage
import axios from "@/config/axios";

axios.get("https://example.com/api/data").then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).